# Why would water pressure at my faucets change after turning off the water main for some time?

Tags: plumbing, water, faucet, water-pressure, plumbing-fixture

I turned off the main water to the house to perform a plumbing repair. The water was off for approximately 5 hours. During that time, I partially drained the water heater tank to flush it (forgot to open a hot water faucet, so it never fully drained...gonna have to to flush it again :/).

Upon turning the water and water heater back on, all of the bathroom sink fixtures "behave" differently. At one, flow is reduced to about half of what it was. At another, turning on both hot and cold fully gives no more flow than turning either one on fully. In the master bath (double sink), one faucet had low pressure before and the other was fine, but now they are opposite - the low pressure one now seems fine and the previously-good one has low pressure / flow.

Main shutoff valve is open fully, as is the valve at the street. Other fixtures in the house (tub, shower, kitchen sink, washer, dishwasher) seem to be operating normally. What could be the cause of this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Debris. Mineral buildup, sand, etc.... You loosened it up, when the water came back on it pushed it into your valves and aerators. Pull the aerators off and clean them out. Of it improves, no need to pull the valves out. Of better, but not the way it was before, turn water off statue faucet and pull the valves out and clean them.   I just did the same thing 2 days ago and have 1 more faucet to clean the valves in.